# Can't assign value to two cells of a dataframe ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have defined a dataframe with 5 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time','u', 'u_hat', 'payoff','power'], index=range(N))
df['u'] = df['u'].astype(object)
df['u_hat'] = df['u_hat'].astype(object)
df['payoff'] = df['payoff'].astype(object)
df['power'] = df['power'].astype(object)
```

At the beginning, the values of the cells are NaN. Then, in a part of my code I want to set the values of the columns 'payoff' and 'power'. I have written a function whose name is revenue and passes two numpy arrays for the output

```
def revenue(offer):
    #some definitions of variables,
    # J and P are ndarrays
    J = (-alpha_net*(P**2) - (beta_net - offer)*P - gamma_net);
  return J,P
```

This is how I am assigning value to the dataframe:

```
initialoffer = [2,  5,  1 ,  3,  50,  10];
df.loc[0,['payoff','power']] = [revenue(initialoffer)]
```

But, I receive the following error:

> ```
> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
> ```

To clarify, this is the output of the revenue function call and its type as well as type of dataframe cells

```
a = revenue(initialoffer)
print(a)
print("\n type of revenue output is",type([revenue(initialoffer)]),"\and the length of it is", len(([revenue(initialoffer)])))
b= np.asanyarray(a,dtype=object)
print("\n type of b is",type(b),"\and the length of it is", len(b))
print("\n type and length of the df.loc[0,['u','u_hat']] are", type(df.loc[0,['u','u_hat']])," and ",len(df.loc[0,['u','u_hat']]), "respectively")
```

This is the output of the above snippet:

> (array([   51.7893083 ,    84.71773404,    14.27980182,    50.44854285,
>
> -2324.48487998,   113.14393764]), array([ 31.27595156,  21.06329296,  30.25086505,  20.91139397,
> -46.23146317,  12.72995963]))
>
> type of revenue output is <class 'list'> nd the length of it is 1
>
> type of b is <class 'numpy.ndarray'> nd the length of it is 2
>
> type and length of the df.loc[0,['u','u_hat']] are <class
> 'pandas.core.series.Series'>  and  2 respectively

So, the problem is that I can pass neither a nor b to the desired cells.
df.loc[0,['u','u_hat']]=b
or

```
df.loc[0,['u','u_hat']]=a
```

Both of the above options gives the following error

> ```
> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
> ```
>
> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unclear what you are trying to do. That being said, I can help a little just by looking at your code:

Based on wanting revenue to return two `np.arrays` and your `df.loc[0,['payoff','power']]` I am assuming you want to set the first row's `payoff` and `power` columns to those lists generated in `revenue` respectively. Your current code will fail as you are taking those two arrays and then putting them into a new list, while still trying to assign to the two columns. This can be resolved as such:

```
df.loc[0,['payoff','power']] = revenue(initialoffer)
```

This will resolve the error code you mentioned above, assuming that `P` is defined somewhere in your `revenue` function.

However, note that if you change your index from the standard index, `df.loc` may also fill in a different line. Thus if you only want the first row to have this solution and only the first row ever, use `df.iloc`.

Also note that it is possible to assign all columns to `object` more easily with just:

```
df = df.astype(object)
```

as opposed to assigning it for each column.

Comment: Dear @WoIVes . Thank you for your response. Your assumption was right. I want to assign value to every index of these two columns in turn. In fact, I have written a for loop in range of index. 
But with this method I can no longer send the dataframe cells to the revenue functions

Comment: df.loc[0,['u','u_hat']] = [np.zeros(6),np.zeros(6)];
how can I resolve this?

Comment: This gives rise in new errors   https://stackoverflow.com/q/65967067/3415597