# how to initialize several columns of a dataframe in the index 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have defined a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time','u', 'u_hat', 'payoff','power'], index=range(N))
```

and a revenue function as below:

```
def revenue(offer):
  N_hmg = 6;
  demand = 70;
  gen_capacity= np.array([8.3000, 3.3000, 5.2000, 6.7000, 3.5000, 5.8500]);
  alpha_net = np.array([0.0003, 0.0004, 0.0004, 0.000175, 0.000175, 0.000175]);
  beta_net = np.array([0.015, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]);
  gamma_net = np.array([10, 20, 15, 12, 13, 14]);
  sigma = np.array([50, 40, 45, 30, 30, 40]);
  miu = 1 - sigma/100;
  rho = miu**(-1);
  ST = sum(rho);
  S_exclude = ST - rho;
  ST = sum(rho);
  a = rho/ST;
  b = 1./(miu + S_exclude**(-1));
  c = 1./(miu*S_exclude + 1);
  f_exclude = np.ones((N_hmg,1))*offer - np.diag(offer);
  P = a*demand - b*offer + rho*(f_exclude.dot(c));
  J = (-alpha_net*(P**2) - (beta_net - offer)*P - gamma_net);
  print(J)
  print(P)
  #return pd.DataFrame(np.array([J, P]).reshape(2,6))
  return J,P
```

Now I want to pass the dataframe cells in column 'u' to the revenue function and

```
#################################  
#Parameter Settings
N_hmg = 6; #number of sellers
# Control Parameters
freq = 2*np.pi; # sampling frequency
dt = 1/freq;
Ttermination = 200; # total period of simulation (in seconds)
ampl = .01;  # amplitude of sinusoidal disturbance
omega = np.array([4,24,44,10,10,36]); # in Hz
K = float(1);   #integration gain
N = int(np.ceil(Ttermination/dt))
##################################

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time','u', 'u_hat', 'payoff','power'], index=range(N)); #dataframe definition

time = dt*np.arange(N);
df['time'] = time;
df.loc[0,['u','u_hat']] = np.asarray([np.zeros(6),np.zeros(6)]);
initialoffer = [2,  5,  1 ,  3,  50,  10];
df.loc[0,['payoff','power']] = revenue(initialoffer)
for i in range(N-1):
  df.loc[i+1,'u_hat'] = np.array(df.loc[i,'u_hat']) + K*dt*ampl*np.sin(omega*(time[i]))*df.loc[i,'payoff'];
  df.loc[i+1,'u'] = np.array(df.loc[i+1,'u_hat']) + ampl*np.sin(omega*(time[700]))
  df.loc[i+1,['payoff','power']] = revenue(df.loc[i+1,'u'])
```

This code will rise this error :

> ---> 47 df.loc[0,['u','u_hat']] = np.asarray([np.zeros(6),np.zeros(6)]); ValueError: Must have equal len
> keys and value when setting with an ndarray

Aside from this error, another error will rise for the revenue function call line:

df.loc[i+1,['payoff','power']] = revenue(df.loc[i+1,'u'])

I wonder what is wrong with this way of value assignment and function call. There must be a misinterpretation

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Emphasis on **minimal**: it should be concise enough that it illustrates what the question is, but without any superfluous baggage. "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away." (Saint-Exupéry)

Answer (score 0):

Your first Error: `df.loc[0,['u','u_hat']] = np.asarray([np.zeros(6),np.zeros(6)]);` I suspect is the same error which occured in your last question: specifically that by putting both `np.zero` arrays into `np.asarray` you are going from the two zero arrays that you want to be in columns `u` and `u_hat` into a single object. You cannot define two columns with only one object, thus you want to pass two objects. To resolve this line should be:

```
df.loc[0,['u','u_hat']] = np.zeros(6), np.zeros(6)
```

I am not sure how to answer your second question. The line `df.loc[i+1,['payoff','power']] = revenue(df.loc[i+1,'u'])` is formatted correctly itself, thus I am guessing the error is a result of the revenue function returning an error. However, the revenue function does seem to be working. Thus I only see two possible errors. 1). because this line is dependent on `u` already being defined and `u` being defined by the previous rows `u_hat` that `u` and `u_hat` could not be defined as a result of the first error to which I provide the solution above (thus breaking the new line) or 2). you are getting back an `nan` value where you are not expecting one. This would be a result of your `u` vectors containing an `nan` value, which then results in the `revenue` function's `np.dot` product returning an `nan` value as `np.dot` cannot have a vector with any `nan` value.